# Two navigation bar without totally the same color

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a TabBar with 5 ViewControllers. Each VC has a navigation bar with the same color but 1 of them seems more dark than the other (whatever the color is) even they are all translucent = YES.

It seems to be NO for this one and i dont know why, any ideas?

thanks

Comment: How do you set the colors? Please show any relevant code.

Comment: they are set in storyboard and then in viewDidLoad:

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:color];

Comment: What is `color`? How much different does it look?

Comment: color is the same on each view, i load it from NSUserDefault.
The user can set manually the color in settings all colors work but one VC is always a bit more darker.

Comment: also the status bar is written in black instead of white for the others

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; solved it